# how direct mapped cache works

Tags: caching, memory-management

Recently, i took lecture related with cache memory and tried to solve the exercises in textbook.

In the textbook there is question related with direct mapped cache.

Given condition:

```
 all with a total of 8 words of data: 

 C1 has 1-word blocks, 

 C2 has 2-word blocks, 

 C3 has 4-word blocks
```

given word address:

```
3, 180, 43, 2, 191, 88, 190, 14, 181, 44, 186, 253
```

following figure is my answer.
[image: my answer]

```
Tag= QUOTIENT(Word Address,8) // total 8 word
Cache 1 index = MOD(QUOTIENT(Word Address,1),8) // 1 word per block, 8 block
Cache 2 index = MOD(QUOTIENT(Word Address,2),4) // 2 word per block, 4 block
Cache 3 index = MOD(QUOTIENT(Word Address,4),2) // 4 word per block, 2 block
```

I made my answer for `tag,index` with above equation.

hit/miss: if  same `tag,index` are already shown in table. then hit else miss

and this one is given solution.
[image: from solution]

Did i miss something? 
Please help me to understand this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think of a cache is like a hallway in a hotel, each room has a number (index) and a guest (tag).  Now lets take the list of addresses and put them into our guestbook.  First we want to run down the hallway until we reach our room (index), once there we want to check the name of the guest (tag) against our guestbook, if it matches great!  That's a hit!

If we get to the room, however, and the name of the guest there doesn't match the name on the guestbook (miss), we have to politely evict him and let the correct guest fill that room.

Now because this is a silly hotel we have to go entry by entry in the guestbook, and once we check off an entry it no longer matters and if a new entry says to evict a guest that just got there, you do it.

Now, if we had a hotel that had rooms that could fit two guests but they had to have the same last name, we would want to find the correct room (index), check both peoples lasts names (tag) then check the first names (offset).

If at anytime the last name doesn't match, you evict the couple and bring in the new couple with the same last name on your guestbook.

So if we look at your answers we can see that instead of ignoring the previous guest that was in the room, you said that there was a hit if at anytime a specific guest was in a specific room.